# Python: Extending the result from the built-in list() function

Tags: python, list, built-in

I have an original list whose contents are determined in another function, and I wish to add the numbers 0 and 5 to the list to make an extended list, without corrupting the original. In this application, I know that 0 and 5 will never be part of the original list, so I am not concerned with duplication. And I am not concerned with the order or the elements either.

1. For reasons discussed in another question, the following does not work because it corrupts the original list:

   ```
   >>> orig = [1,6]
   >>> extended = orig
   >>> extended.extend([0,5])
   >>> extended
   [1, 6, 0, 5]
   >>> orig
   [1, 6, 0, 5]
   ```
2. One of the solutions proposed is to use the built-in list() function. This produces the desired result:

   ```
   >>> orig = [1,6]
   >>> extended = list(orig)
   >>> extended.extend([0,5])
   >>> extended
   [1, 6, 0, 5]
   >>> orig
   [1, 6]
   ```
3. Then I attempted to combine the 2nd and 3rd lines of 2. This produces a 'None' result, and only if you print it.

   ```
   >>> orig = [1,6]
   >>> extended = list(orig).extend([0,5])
   >>> extended
   >>> print extended
   None
   ```
4. What I eventually coded, which is neater than any of the previous attempts, is this, using concatenation.

   ```
   >>> orig = [1,6]
   >>> extended = orig + [0,5]
   >>> extended
   [1, 6, 0, 5]
   >>> orig
   [1, 6]
   ```

But my question is, why won't example 3 work? It looks reasonable (to me), and it doesn't return an error. It just produces 'None'.

I am using Python 2.7.8.

Answer (score 1):

`extend` is an *inplace* operation, like `list.sort`, `list.append` it affects the original list. All those methods because they don't return any value  return `None` so you are simply seeing the return value of extend when you `extended = list(orig).extend([0,5])`.

```
In [6]:  l = [1,2,3]  
In [7]: e = l.extend([4,5])    
In [8]: print e
None
In [9]:  l = [1,2,3]  
In [10]: a = l.append(6)    
In [11]: print a
None
```